# Send all fields in email with HTML Webform

Tags: html, css, forms

I have created a webform in HTML 5 and CSS 3. I would like the action to be set to email and send all of the fields.

Here is my currently existing code, using js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1njosLa/

This is the result from the email:
`"message=128+Baker+Street%0D%0A%0D%0ALondon&email=john_doe%40example.com&website=http%3A%2F%2Fetetet.com&message="`

So my questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to send the form to an email address without
   having to open up outlook? I sure there are but I would just like a
   decent and hopefully quick tutorial which I can just add on to my
   existing HTML and CSS?
2. How can I get all fields to send in an email?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For that you have to learn server scripting language (like PHP). You have completed only the 1st Phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with HTML only, you can PHP (a server side language), you can find a guide on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp.

Comment: 'you have to use PHP'. You should not state that, only that he must use 'a server side language, for example PHP'.